# Should a REST API Controller contain logic about decomposing the request body?

Tags: python, rest, api-design

I'm implementing a backend service where I have a PUT endpoint to update the data in the database.
The data looks like this in a PUT request:

```
[
{"device": {
    "key1": "value",
    "key2": "value2",
    "key3": "value3",
    "key4": "value4",
    }
},
{"device": {
    "key1": "value",
    "key2": "value2",
    "key3": "value3",
    "key4": "value4",
    }
}
]
```

Which one is better:

1. Iterating this list in the **Controller** class and calling the repository.saveDevice(device) for each device in the request body, or
2. Passing the whole request body to something like repository.saveDevice(devices) and then iterate this in the **Repository** class to update each device?